# SQL Server SSIS and Oracle Data Pump

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, datapump

I'm a beginner, and trying to improve my knowledge on DB side.

I am learning SSIS with SQL Server 2008R2. Going by the tutorials from Web, I feel like this is somewhat similar to what I've read about Oracle Data Pump.

Can someone enlighten me, if there is similarity between two SSIS and Data Pump.
If they are totally different, please forgive me for this question. Else, let me know how they are similar.

Regards,
Justin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data Pump is not a complete ETL tool,it is a feature in Oracle 11g.It transfers the data from a single file to a single destination.With SSIs you got all the extraction ,transformation and loading facilities.

```
Corresponding to SSIS ,oracle has oracle warehouse builder.

Oracle data pump is an alternative to EXPORT and Import utility in SQL SERVER.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of Data Pump but initial googlings show it is more related to being a Data Flow Task within an SSIS package than being a substitute for a whole SSIS package.  Data Pump is simply porting data from a single source to a single destination.  An SSIS package can facilitate extracting, transforming, and loading any amount of sources to any amount of destinations within the same package.  You also get the extensibility (if that is a word?) of writing .NET code or any other 3rd party assemblies that you would like to use to further do manipulation of data.  You can also do file and DB maintenance with an SSIS package (clean up after processing of files, maintaining backups, etc.).